# Content Organizer Rule giving a warning message

Tags: 2013, content-organizer, drop-off-library, content-organizer-rule

I have `Content Organizer` enabled on root site collection, which transfers document to the appropriate library of subsite. I have achieved it by creating rules in root site collection as well as subsite so that it does move document to proper document library.

Now my question is when I upload document like images (*.png/*.jpg) format, it does move document to proper location as per the rules applied.

When I select any Microsoft document like Word, PowerPoint or Excel, it moves the document but shows below warning message:

> The document was submitted successfully. **Its location will change pending action from a site administrator.** For now, you can continue to access the document here: https://mysharepoint/sites/recordcenter/_layouts/15/DocIdRedir.aspx?ID=XQ3SJ2ZC36RJ-11-781&hintUrl=DropOffLibrary/TestExcel.xlsx

[image]

I don't really understand why it is going in pending state. Even with this warning message, I get my document copied to the exact library as per the condition in rule but the actual document stays in `Drop-off Library`. I have tried finding solution for the same but didn't get any proper solution for the same.

Can someone please help me if you have overcome the same problem?

Comment: Check this - [SharePoint Record Center not routing documents](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/26785/sharepoint-record-center-not-routing-documents)

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response, I have checked that already but for me that didnt work. I have checked all my required fields are filled. Is there anyway I can check the log for this?

Comment: can you run the `Content Organizer Processing timer job` and then check ?
also if possible enable verbose logging and check the ULS logs

Comment: I have run the `Content Organizer Processing time job` for my web application and checked but the same warning message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging a lot, I have found out that my destination library has an `event receiver` and it was also updating document properties after moving document. So by checking ULS found that :

> w3wp.exe (0x1FA0)                         0x2B2C  Document Management Server      Content Organizer               cf6o    Unexpected  Routing Engine: File DropOffLibrary/TestExcel.xlsx could not be routed to /subsite1/DestinationLibrary in site https://mysharepoint/dev/subsite1/: The file DestinationLibrary/TestExcel.xlsx has been modified by SHAREPOINT\system on 22 Jun 2017 07:17:23 -0500. 901efe9d-9876-80c4-9b78-62fde5f78c4f

Once I had de-activated that feature of event receiver, all files were successfully being moved to the destination library.

I hope this is helpful for someone who might get stuck in such issues.